# How to execute a php script from another php script?

Tags: php, shell, security, exec

I have some PHP files called **file1.php, file2.php, file3.php**. Now, I want to run these PHP files one by one from other PHP file called **all.php**. I mean file2.php will be executed after file1.php was completed. File3.php will be executed after file2.php was completed. How to do that ?

Can I use exec function ? It is safe for my hosting ? I am using Cpanel in shared hosting. There is any way to do that but safe for my content in hosting ?

Thank you very  much !

Comment: include what you need in all.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [**include()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

```
include('file1.php');
include('file2.php');
include('file3.php');
```

or [**include_once()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

```
include_once('file1.php');
include_once('file2.php');
include_once('file3.php');
```

or [**require**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)   or [**require_once**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

```
require 'file1.php';
require 'file2.php';
require 'file3.php';
```

=> `require()` will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script

=>  `include()` will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

Answer (score 1):

in the file `all.php` you can do:

```
include('file1.php');
include('file2.php');
include('file3.php');
```

Comment: when you include the file, it's as if you have the file written at the location where you have included it !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use 'exec' function or as alternate 'system', 'passthru' functions

But in that case your files i.e. 'file1.php', 'file2.php' and 'file3.php'

- will execute as cli execution.
- you will not get http variables like $_REQUEST, $_SESSION etc.
- security is depend upon code what you written in file1.php.
- you code will execute as a permission of apache user if you are calling all.php from web url (so probably it will be safe).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a tottaly seperate script U could albo use exec (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)